# Starting Redis as a service on OS X with Homebrew

Tags: mac-osx, redis, launchctl

I installed Redis via `brew install redis` and attempted to add it as a service via:

```
ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/redis/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.redis.plist
```

These didn't generate any errors; however, it appears that Redis does not start. If I run `redis-cli ping`, I get back `Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379: Connection refused`.

I can manually run `redis-server` in another terminal window, but I'd like to have Redis auto-start on login.

I also tried uninstalling Redis, reinstalling it, and using `brew services` to manage services (`brew services` works fine for me with the installations of MongoDB and Cassandra).

I haven't seen others having this problem so I'm not sure how to diagnose. If anyone has any advice, much appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

make sure you've tapped the services first:

`brew tap homebrew/services`

then try:

`brew services [start/stop/restart] redis`

you can also start and stop redis with:

`sudo launchctl start io.redis.redis-server`

`sudo launchctl stop io.redis.redis-server`

to make your life easier, you can add aliases for these commands to your .bash_profile.

```
alias redisstart='sudo launchctl start io.redis.redis-server'
alias redisstop='sudo launchctl stop io.redis.redis-server'
```

then you can just start and stop redis by typing `redisstart` and `redisstop`.

another way you can go about this is adding redis as a background service:

`sudo vim /Library/LaunchDaemons/io.redis.redis-server.plist`

then copy and paste the following into the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>io.redis.redis-server</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/local/bin/redis-server</string>
        <string>/usr/local/etc/redis.conf</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Won't this run redis as root? Is that a good idea in a production environment?

Comment: This is for local dev. I mean, who has an Xserve really?

Comment: long live the mac mini server!

Answer (score 1):

```
launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.redis.plist
```

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! It looks like you may have the knowledge to provide good Answer here, but please consider reading [How do I write a good Answer?](http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-answer) in our help center and then revise the Answer. Your Commands/Code/Settings may technically be the solution but  some explanation and context is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You may have edited the conf file to daemonize redis when you used to start redis manually before. Check it and change `daemonize` to `no`, then retry `brew services`